# Can we use a WebView to display remote web content in UWP apps?

Tags: webview, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

The Windows run-time API class WebView in Windows Phone 8 was for displaying local HTML content, not web browsing.

Microsoft's Matt Small wrote in [Ten things you need to know about WebView](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx) that a WebView object is not a general-purpose browser, and apps which display online content in a WebView as their primary purpose will be rejected. Small was writing about Windows 8 Phone in 2012.

Has that position changed for WebView objects in UWP apps in 2016? The [Windows 10 XAML documentation itself suggests using the http or https schemes for remote content, and the ms-appx-web scheme for local content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx).

The WP8 [WebBrowser class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.105).aspx) looked promising, but doesn't seem to be in W10M.

If WebViews are not permitted to browse the web, are there any other objects, frameworks, or projects that would suitable for displaying web content as their primary purpose in UWP apps? Ideally, something that runs JavaScript and functions like a real browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we use a WebView to display remote web content in UWP apps?

Yes you can, it works well, it uses Edge engine and runs javascript and everything like a real browser.

It was on news few months ago that [Microsoft’s Edge team is encouraging developers to build browsers](http://www.winbeta.org/news/microsofts-edge-team-encouraging-developers-build-browsers). You can also take a look at the [JSBrowser](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/JSBrowser) app, it is a simple web browser written in javascript and uses the [WebView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) control.

However, even though it works well, it is still not perfect, it has problems like memory management issues and limited access to the web content through app but it is good enough to be used as an in-app browser (I'm doing so in a live app).

> If WebViews are not permitted to browse the web, are there any other
>   objects, frameworks, or projects that would suitable for displaying
>   web content as their primary purpose in UWP apps? Ideally, something
>   that runs JavaScript and functions like a real browser.

It is definitely permitted to browser web using WebViews but I have no idea if there is any alternative for WebView in UWP.